# ISAPI_rewrite multiple domains and rewrite urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

**For .htaccess file, with ISAPI_rewrite**
I'm designer not coder, need help if someone can code for rewrite urls for SEO
 - Thanks in advance.

I have multiple domains on same server and each domain's content is sharing folders:
(www.)domain1.com/
(www.)domain2.com/
all should rewrite and url show http(s)://www.maindomain1.com
and content is from root/sitefolder1/index.php

and same for other pages like:
(www.)domain1.com/about.php
(www.)domain2.com/about.php
should rewrite and url show http(s)://www.maindomain1.com/about.php
and content is from root/sitefolder1/about.php

but contact page need to rewrite like:
(www.)domain1.com/contact/person-name1
(www.)domain2.com/contact/person-name1
should rewrite and url show http(s)://www.maindomain1.com/contact/person-name1
and content is from root/sitefolder1/contact.php?p=person-name1

and for blog I am using wordpress so need rewrite for that too,
I am using permalinks option "Post name http://www.example.com/sample-post/"
(www.)domain1.com/blog
(www.)domain2.com/blog
should rewrite and url show http(s)://www.maindomain1.com/blog
and content from root/sitefolder1/blog/ (not sure, what page wordpress use)

(www.)domain1.com/blog/post1
(www.)domain2.com/blog/post1
should rewrite and url show http(s)://www.maindomain1.com/blog/post1
and content from root/sitefolder1/blog/ (not sure, what page wordpress use)

(www.)domain1.com/blog/category/post2
(www.)domain2.com/blog/category/post2
should rewrite and url show http(s)://www.maindomain1.com/blog/category/post2
and content from root/sitefolder1/blog/ (not sure, what page or folder wordpress use)

and same process for other domains as domain1 and doamin2 like:
(www.)domain3.com
(www.)domain4.com
all should rewrite and url show http(s)://www.maindomain2.com
and content from root/sitefolder2/index.php

Answer (score 0):

The starting point for you can be helicontech.com. Start with FAQ - http://www.helicontech.com/forum/10648-FAQ.html, move to Examples Section - http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/examples.htm. There you'll find the first couple rules to redirect domains. In order to use WP - read http://www.helicontech.com/articles/isapi-rewrite-with-wordpress/